# Cannot alter title on user profile page

Tags: 7

I've created a custom module called **renameprofile** to alter the title on my user page, but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what is causing this issue? Btw this is on the `?q=user` page.

**renameprofile.module**

```
<?php
function renameprofile_page_alter() {  

  global $user;  

  if(drupal_get_title() === isset($user->name)) {  
    drupal_set_title('My Sharecab');  
  }  
}
?>
```

**renameprofile.info**

```
name = Rename user profile page title
description = This module renames the profile page title
core = 7.x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's an odd approach with `=== isset()` basically checking if `drupal_get_title == TRUE;` whereas `drupal_get_title` returns a string title.

Something like this should work, in template.php or module (clear cache).

It will set the `$title` variable for `page.tpl.php`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page
 */
function MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  // Set title on user account pages.
  if ($account = menu_get_object('user')) {
    $variables['title'] = t('My Sharecab');
  }
}
```